# StdOut is spammed with 'C:\fakepath' warnings integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible using Selenium through C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-firefoxdriver, renderer

I am using Selenium Firefox Web Driver. It is working properly but when I worked command line with "dotnet run", some warning logs that I did not solve, arose on the command line. How can I solve this issue?

[image: console warning logs]

```
var options = new FirefoxOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--headless");
            IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), options);
            var link = "ANY LINK";

            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(link);
            driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("ANY CLASS NAME")).Click(); 
            driver.Dispose();
```

Here is some warnings because of broken image link

```
1578640820834   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1578640820834   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1578640820834   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1578640820834   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
WARN: compileToBinary(259):
C:\fakepath(337,18-133): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(343,62-116): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(360,75-84): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(363,50-59): warning X3556: integer modulus may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(383,33-90): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(174,1-6): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (dyn_index_vec4_float4)
C:\fakepath(289,25-29): error X4576: Input array signature parameter  cannot be indexed dynamically.

WARN: compileToBinary(259):
C:\fakepath(337,18-133): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(343,62-116): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(360,75-84): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(363,50-59): warning X3556: integer modulus may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(383,33-90): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(174,1-6): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (dyn_index_vec4_float4)
C:\fakepath(289,25-29): error X4576: Input array signature parameter  cannot be indexed dynamically.

WARN: compileToBinary(259):
C:\fakepath(360,75-84): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(363,50-59): warning X3556: integer modulus may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(174,1-6): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (dyn_index_vec4_float4)
C:\fakepath(225,1): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (f_distance_aa)
C:\fakepath(262,1): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (f_do_clip)

[Child 7840, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1572401533/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341
[Ch1578640823372        Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 58853
1578640829566   Marionette      INFO    Stopped listening on port 58853
[Parent 18380, Gecko_IOThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1572401533/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341
[Child 23108, Chrome_ChildThread] WARNING: pipe error: 109: file z:/task_1572401533/build/src/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/common/ipc_channel_win.cc, line 341
[GPU
###!!! [Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These warning messages...

```
WARN: compileToBinary(259):
C:\fakepath(337,18-133): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(343,62-116): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(360,75-84): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(363,50-59): warning X3556: integer modulus may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(383,33-90): warning X3571: pow(f, e) will not work for negative f, use abs(f) or conditionally handle negative values if you expect them
C:\fakepath(174,1-6): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (dyn_index_vec4_float4)
C:\fakepath(289,25-29): error X4576: Input array signature parameter  cannot be indexed dynamically.
.
WARN: compileToBinary(259):
C:\fakepath(360,75-84): warning X3556: integer divides may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(363,50-59): warning X3556: integer modulus may be much slower, try using uints if possible.
C:\fakepath(174,1-6): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (dyn_index_vec4_float4)
C:\fakepath(225,1): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (f_distance_aa)
C:\fakepath(262,1): warning X4000: use of potentially uninitialized variable (f_do_clip)
```

...is the result of `StdOut` being spammed with `C:\fakepath` when **Webrender** is enabled.

---

### Analysis

When Firefox is opened with WebRender enabled and if the `stdout` is captured thiese `warning` messeges were observed. These `warning` messages were the result of some **shader** change in **WebRender** in `GPU -> ANGLE` module.

We have analyzed and discussed this issue at length in the following threads:

- **Mozilla - Bugzilla**: [StdOut is spammed with 'C:\fakepath' when Webrender is enabled](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1443747)
- **Chromium - Bugs**: [Issue 765576: WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(51)](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=765576)

Finally, this issue was solved through this [merge](https://github.com/servo/webrender/pull/3014) / [commit](https://github.com/servo/webrender/commit/211e3d6f841596e460d404d3580f231edfd22d36)

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- Upgrade *JDK* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u222**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium* to  current levels [**Version 3.141.59**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *GeckoDriver* to [**GeckoDriver v0.26.0**](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) level.
- GeckoDriver is present in the desired location.
- GeckoDriver is having executable permission for non-root users.
- Upgrade *Firefox* version to ***Firefox v70.0*** levels.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- (*WindowsOS only*) Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- (*LinuxOS only*) [Free Up and Release the Unused/Cached Memory in Ubuntu/Linux Mint](http://www.yourownlinux.com/2013/10/how-to-free-up-release-unused-cached-memory-in-linux.html) before and after the execution of your *Test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `Test` as a non-root user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.